# use generator as subprocess input; got "I/O operation on closed file" exception

Tags: python, subprocess, generator, popen

I have a large file that needs to be processed before feeding to another command. I could save the processed data as a temporary file but would like to avoid it. I wrote a generator that processes each line at a time then following script to feed to the external command as input. however I got "I/O operation on closed file" exception at the second round of the loop:

```
cmd = ['intersectBed', '-a', 'stdin', '-b', bedfile]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for entry in my_entry_generator: # <- this is my generator
    output = p.communicate(input='\t'.join(entry) + '\n')[0]
    print output
```

I read another similar question that uses p.stdin.write. but still had the same problem.

What I did wrong?

[edit]
I replaced last two statements with following (thanks SpliFF):

```
    output = p.communicate(input='\t'.join(entry) + '\n')
    if output[1]: print "error:", output[1]
    else: print output[0]
```

to see if there was any error by the external program. But no. 
Still have the same exception at p.communicate line.

Comment: For future reference, including the actual traceback you get is a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `communicate` method of `subprocess.Popen` objects can only be called once. What it does is it sends the input you give it to the process *while* reading all the stdout and stderr output. And by "all", I mean it waits for the process to exit so that it knows it has all output. Once `communicate` returns, the process no longer exists.

If you want to use `communicate`, you have to either restart the process in the loop, or give it a single string that is *all* the input from the generator. If you want to do streaming communication, sending data bit by bit, then you have to not use `communicate`. Instead, you would need to write to `p.stdin` while reading from `p.stdout` and `p.stderr`. Doing this is tricky, because you can't tell which output is caused by which input, and because you can easily run into deadlocks. There are third-party libraries that can help you with this, like Twisted.

If you want to do this *interactively*, sending some data and then waiting for and processing the result before sending more data, things get even harder. You should probably use a third-party library like `pexpect` for that.

Of course, if you can get away with just starting the process inside the loop, that would be a lot easier:

```
cmd = ['intersectBed', '-a', 'stdin', '-b', bedfile]
for entry in my_entry_generator:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = p.communicate(input='\t'.join(entry) + '\n')[0]
    print output
```

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. Looks like subprocess + external command is not a proper solution for my problem. Luckily I found a python wrapper for the command that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your intersectBed application is exiting with an error but since you aren't printing any stderr data you can't see it. Try:

```
result = p.communicate(input='\t'.join(entry) + '\n')
if result[1]:
  print "error:", result[1]
else:
  print result[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It still has the same error at p.communicate(input=...) line