# Popen.communicate raises ValueError: 'I/O operation on closed file'

Tags: python, io, subprocess, valueerror

I get the following error when I run my code.

```
    Uncaught exception <class 'ValueError'>: I/O operation on closed file.Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/gidumah/miniconda/envs/ytune/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "/home/gidumah/miniconda/envs/ytune/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/home/gidumah/ytopt/ytopt/ytopt/search/ambs.py", line 128, in <module>
        search.main()
      File "/home/gidumah/ytopt/ytopt/ytopt/search/ambs.py", line 105, in main
        results = list(self.evaluator.get_finished_evals())
      File "/home/gidumah/ytopt/ytopt/ytopt/evaluator/evaluate.py", line 200, in get_finished_evals
        y = future.result()
      File "/home/gidumah/ytopt/ytopt/ytopt/evaluator/subprocess_evaluator.py", line 41, in result
        stdout, stderr_data = self.proc.communicate()
      File "/home/gidumah/miniconda/envs/ytune/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 951, in communicate
        stdout = self.stdout.read()
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The code I was running is `subprocess_evaluator.py`, which is given below:

```
class PopenFuture:
    FAIL_RETURN_VALUE = Evaluator.FAIL_RETURN_VALUE

    def __init__(self, args, parse_fxn):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf-8')

        self._state = 'active'
        self._result = None
        self._parse = parse_fxn

    def _poll(self):
        if not self._state == 'active':
            return
        retcode = self.proc.poll()
        if retcode is None:
            self._state = 'active'
            stdout, stderr_data = self.proc.communicate()
            tmp_res = self._parse(stdout)
            if tmp_res != sys.float_info.max:
                self._result = tmp_res
        elif retcode == 0:
            self._state = 'done'
        else:
            self._state = 'failed'

    def result(self):
        if self._result is not None:
            return self._result
        self.proc.wait()
        stdout, stderr_data = self.proc.communicate()
        if self.done:
            self._result = self._parse(stdout)
        else:
            self._result = self.FAIL_RETURN_VALUE
            logger.error(f"Eval failed: {stdout}")
        ####
        # if stdout:
        #     print (stdout)#.split('\n')[:-2])#)[:-1])
        ####   
        return self._result
```

It says the error is in line 41, which is given as `stdout, stderr_data = self.proc.communicate()`

Is there something I am not doing right with the communicate call?

Comment: In the future, please paste code and tracebacks as plain text surrounded by \`\`\` code tags, instead of whatever IDE option which generates HTML formatting that I had to remove manually.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Popen.**communicate**(input=None, timeout=None)
>
> Interact with process:
> Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until
> end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate and set the
> returncode attribute. The optional input argument should be data to be
> sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the
> child. If streams were opened in text mode, input must be a string.
> Otherwise, it must be bytes.

Note that it waits for the process to terminate. Therefore `Popen.communicate` cannot be run more than once. The error in the context of `Popen.communicate` means that the program already terminated the process and closed the pipes, and raised the exception upon second `communicate` call.

It seems that you are using code of the [`ytopt` library](https://github.com/ytopt-team/ytopt/blob/bdb7b47d75abd40870328c0e4153d499a6eb33d4/ytopt/evaluator/subprocess_evaluator.py#L11). Please check if you use the code correctly, note that it calls `communicate()` in few different places, sometimes with passing on ValueErrors but sometimes not. Also, check out Thomas Wouters [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892372/8007403) to the problem:

> If you want to use communicate, you have to either restart the process
> in the loop, or give it a single string that is all the input from the
> generator. If you want to do streaming communication, sending data bit
> by bit, then you have to not use communicate. Instead, you would need
> to write to p.stdin while reading from p.stdout and p.stderr. Doing
> this is tricky, because you can't tell which output is caused by which
> input, and because you can easily run into deadlocks. There are
> third-party libraries that can help you with this, like Twisted.
>
> If you want to do this interactively, sending some data and then
> waiting for and processing the result before sending more data, things
> get even harder. You should probably use a third-party library like
> pexpect for that.
>
> Of course, if you can get away with just starting the process inside
> the loop, that would be a lot easier:
>
> ```
> cmd = ['intersectBed', '-a', 'stdin', '-b', bedfile]
> for entry in my_entry_generator:
>     p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>     output = p.communicate(input='\t'.join(entry) + '\n')[0]
>     print output
> ```